# Webhooks to desktop

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, webhooks

[This document](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push) states that WebHooks requires you to register a server, with a URL and all, before confirming the website is yours.

I wish to use this API in a (C#) desktop, to get notified when a remote drive change has been made.

I tried registering a domain using an IP address, with the link provided in the document, but it does not work.

Is this API really only to be used by back-end servers?

Comment: have a look at https://ngrok.com/docs#expose

Comment: Omg, pinoyyid; this seems perfect.

Comment: Nevermind; I'm too poor to pay for that...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[To use push notifications, you need to do three things](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/push):

- Register the domain of your receiving URL. For example, if you plan to use https://example.com/notifications as your receiving URL, you need to register https://example.com.
- Set up your receiving URL, or "Webhook" callback receiver.
- Set up a notification channel for each resource endpoint you want to watch.

The domain must be a URL hosted.  Your not going to be able o use it on a normal pc unless you have a webserver installed on that.   With a registered domain and not just an ip address.

Comment: So, to check for changes, will a desktop application *have* to poll?

Comment: Yup you wont be able to use notifications.  I have just created a windows service in the past to check the API. You will have to remember to keep an eye on your Quota don't poll to often.

Comment: Are you the owner of Daimto.com? I've used your tutorials for parts of my application!

Comment: Yup I am glad to have been of help.

Comment: It wouldn't be worth relaying the notification through a dedicated server, right?

Comment: It will depend on what your system is doing.  Polling directly from your windows app to the API is going to eat your quota.   If you can set up a server to handle notifications nicely.  You can then have as many windows applications as you want reading from the server without touching the API and eating your quota.   If this is a single install its probably not worth if it.  If its a multi user system its defiantly going to be worth it.

Comment: Oh, ok; thank you very much for, even more, help. One of the aims of my application was to refrain from polling; however, this won't be viable with its small scale.

Comment: Polling is ugly but sometimes unavoidable.

Comment: What does the second bullet point refers to specifically : "Set up your receiving URL, or "Webhook" callback receiver.". What does setup mean here? I know that I have to pass the URL of my server program (php file in my case) receiving the notification as the "address" parameter in the "watch" request. So is this what they mean by setting up the "Webhook" callback receiver?